# How is it possible to create an instance of an abstract class?

Tags: c#

How is it possible for me to return an instance of the `Type` class with the `Type.GetType(string typeName)` method, when the class has previously been marked as abstract?

This is the code I used to save my `MyClass` class into the `obj` variable.

```cs
Type obj = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication.MyClass");
```

This is what I found when I went to the definition for the `Type` class.

```
[NullableAttribute(0)]
[NullableContextAttribute(1)]
public abstract class Type : MemberInfo, IReflect
{

    [return: NullableAttribute(2)]
    public static Type? GetType(string typeName);

    /*
    / Other class members that, for the sake of keeping this question short, haven't been pasted 
    / into this Code sample.
    */
}
```

Comment: The question says you are wanting to return a instance of the "Type" class. The code that you shared does exactly what you want. Are you meaning that you want to create an instance of the "MyClass" class?

Comment: Very interesting question. You can't create an instance of an abstract class, so an instance/object of type "Type" appears to be a violation of that. I'm only (wild) guessing it is a unique abstract class that the .NET Framework treats differently.

Comment: @FrankFajardo Actually, its because `obj` is not an instance of `Type`, it's an instance of `RuntimeType`, which inherits from and is assignable to `Type`.  See David's answer.

Comment: @Amy, I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is it possible for me to return an instance of the "Type" class
>   with the "Type.GetType(string typeName)" method, when the class has
>   previously been marked as abstract?

Because the actual object returned is a concrete sub-type of the abstract type "Type".  To see this run:

```
 Type obj = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication.MyClass");
 var typeName = obj.GetType().Name;
```

From the docs:

> Type is an abstract base class that allows multiple implementations.
>   The system will always provide the derived class RuntimeType.

[Type Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

One method you can use is to call `ReflectionOnlyGetType`. You must have both the name of the assembly and full class name. You can pass parameters to control case sensitivity and whether exceptions are thrown if no type is found.

```
var type = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType("ConsoleApplication.Example, ConsoleApplication", true, true);
```

If you know the containing assembly, you can use the Assembly directly:

```
var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly; // Use any class from target assembly
var type = assembly.GetType("ConsoleApplication.MyClass");
```

If you are using .NET Core, it seems the `ReflectionOnlyGetType` is not yet implemented ([source code just throws `PlatformNotSupported` exception when called](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Type.cs#L386)), so you may have to find a way to use the second approach (which does work for .NET Core).